# Warning when setting window.location to download a file

Tags: javascript, download, http-accept-header

I am setting the window.location to download a file ("/foo/bar"). Now, the download works in google chrome, but it emits this warning:

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/csv:
```

These are the response headers that are set according to google chrome:

```
Content-Description:File Transfer  
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="foo.csv"  
Content-Length:29  
Content-Type:application/csv
Date:Sun, 14 Dec 2014 20:53:33 GMT  
Server:http-kit
```

Any ideas if I can set the accept header on js side anyhow to omit this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an anchor tag

```
<a href="fileLink" download="filename">Download</a>
```

make sure for the download attribute you put the extension type of the file like .html, .css, .js whatever it is

Comment: But I don't have a link at all. I am doing a ajax request and afterwards set window.location.

Comment: create one dynamically? using javascript **document.createElement('a')**

Comment: And then triggering a click on the link via js? I have never done that before, but it sounds like it might work.

Comment: **var downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
downloadLink.href = "fileLink";
downloadLink.download = "fileName";**


I believe the link has to be on the document so:

**document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
downloadLink.click();**

Comment: This works, at least there is no warning anymore and I can download the file. Thank you.

Comment: Still attempt to see how to do it with the url that way you don't have to mess with the dom. also look up on **window.open** to download files